# equal height using % unit and relative to image height

Tags: html, css

Here is my fiddle:

### JSFiddle

You can find the sources [here](https://jsfiddle.net/outlander/nax1yaqj/6/) in a JSFiddle.

### CSS

```
.container { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  float: right;
}
.box {
  margin-top: -350px;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}
.box:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    float:right;
}
.top-section {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 175px;
}
.bottom-section {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 175px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
            <img src="http://st.hzcdn.com/simgs/7d0137b70f7848d3_3-3892/modern-futons.jpg">
            <div class="top-section">
                some text.......
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-section">
                some other text.....
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
            <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MzAwWDMwMA==/z/JLYAAOSwxH1UBi1~/$_35.JPG?set_id=2">
            <div class="top-section">
                some text.......
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-section">
                some other text.....
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two divs stacked on top of each other (div.box) using margin-top. each div.box is divided into 3 section: a section for a picture, one for some text and another for some other text.

I'm trying to make div.top-section and div.bottom-section the same height and my problem is this:

I want my pictures to be responsive using width:100%;height:auto but I want at the same time, whenever a user resize the window, div.top-section and div.bottom-section don't loose their height relevant to the picture. I mean I want div.top-section and div.bottom-section, each have 1/2 image height and using % unit and not pixel.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No,you can't just use css only. you need to use Javascript (or Jquery) to find the height of img every time you resize browser's window and set height of div box(left side) to the height of img(you should put div.top-section and div.bottom-section in another div)

Comment: using js/jQuery is not safe because whenever I use $(document).ready(); jQuery can't read the height of images cause images are not loaded yet and therefore there is no height of image!

Comment: using $(window).load() instead,it can safe to get height of image

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with absolute positioning.  You can position the container your holding this all in to relative and then posiiton all of your inner content to absolute.  Then give your container a padding-bottom of a percentage and play with this percentage until you get your desired height.  Then give your text section absolute positioning and a height of 50% and your image a height of 100% and width of 50% and position this to the right.

This can be acheived one of 2 ways.  You can use just the image and position that absolutely like so:

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-1">
    Text 1
  </div>
  <div class="text-2">
    Text 2
  </div>
  <img  src="http://st.hzcdn.com/simgs/7d0137b70f7848d3_3-3892/modern-futons.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
}
.text-1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.text-2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
.container img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle of that method [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/u4Lbceqh/)

Next if you don't want to lose the aspect ratio of the image.  Say you have a tall image and a short image and you want to use this multiple times on your page.  You can put another div in the container and position this to the right and place your image as the background of this div like so:

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-1">
    Text 1
  </div>
  <div class="text-2">
    Text 2
  </div>
  <div class="image-section" style="background:url('http://st.hzcdn.com/simgs/7d0137b70f7848d3_3-3892/modern-futons.jpg')"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
}
.text-1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.text-2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
.image-section{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-size:cover !Important;
  background-position:center !Important;
  backgroung-repeat:no-repeat !Important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle of that [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/9f2ux3tj/)

Comment: Thank you but I cant use absolute positioning and that's why I choose margin-top to stack all elements. I'm looking for a solution for my scenario.

Comment: Can I ask why you can't use absolute positioning?

Comment: Because if I use absolute positioning, then my other elements that are under the element with position:absolute, take it's place and it's not what I want.

Comment: The container holding the absolute positioned items is positioned relative so anything placed outside of this container will not be affected by your absolute positioning.  Maybe it was a bad example to use container as the classname but look at the following fiddle to help you better understand what I am talking about.  https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/z891qwLy/